# Ctrl + W shortcut of IntelliJ idea equivalent in MyEclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, myeclipse

I am using `IntelliJ IDEA` as my environment at past and `MyEclipse` at know. You can using `Ctrl + W` shortcut for selected(and highlighted) a word  in`IntelliJ`. I found `Ctrl + W` shortcut equivalent in `MyEclipse`, it is `Alt + Shift + Up/Down Arrow key`. These equivalent (In `IntelliJ` and `MyEclipse`) have a differenc when you are using for a string in `""` into your code. 
for sample a string such as : "HelloWorld" . 
In `IntellJ` using `Ctrl + W` in `IntelliJ` once, only `HelloWorld` highlighted but using `Alt + Shift + Up/Down Arrow key` in `MyEclipse` all string includes of `""` characters highlighted.

My question is: I want `MyEclipse` shortcut equivalent exactly to `IntelliJ`.Is there solution for this request?

(Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology or grammar, I am learning english language.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid Eclipse dose not support such behavior as far as I know. Intellij implementation is smarter.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I thought like you then I guess maybe exist a way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but if you double-click between the opening quote mark and the first character, just the characters get selected. This works even if there are spaces in the string but the interesting thing is that the same technique works for the contents of braces and parentheses - and probably other constructs too.

Comment: You are right, but I want do this task by keyboard no by mouse.